# Processing: how to check if JSON Objects are bound

Tags: java, json, api, processing

Since the Processing forum is down I hope one of you guys can help me out.

I made a Processing sketch that pulls data from an API (test here: http://www.europeana.eu/portal/api/console.html ) in JSON-format and reads some fields of this data for visualization. Everything works fine so far except when there are fields that are not bound to every JSONObject.

This is the code for the retrieval of the data:

```
JSONObject json;
json = loadJSONObject("data.json"); // loading my JSON file into the object
JSONArray CHOData = json.getJSONArray("items"); // array of the items I want data from

for (int i = 0; i < CHOData.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject CHO = CHOData.getJSONObject(i); // get a specific item
    JSONArray previewObj = CHO.getJSONArray("edmPreview"); // this field is an array, so I need to store it in a JSONArray object first
    String[] previewArray = previewObj.getStringArray(); // here I store it in my actual string array
    String preview = previewArray[0]; // I only need the first element
}
```

As you can see, I want the first string of the "edmPreview" array in the object. When I run the sketch, I get an error: "JSONObject["edmPreview"] not found."
This is of course because not every item has such an object. But how can I test if there is an object with this name in an item? I tried with if(CHO.getJSONObject("edmPreview") != null), but same error. Is there a way to look into the JSONObject and check the data values for something called "edmPreview"? There is no such function explained in the Processing reference.

The JSON file essentially looks as follows:

```
{
"items": [
   {
     "id": "someID",
     "edmPreview": [
       "http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=someimage.jpg"
     ],
     // some other fields
   }, // some other items
]
}
```

I'm new to this JSON-stuff, so maybe I miss something important... Thanks for the help!

Comment: What JSON library are you using?  Include your imports.

Comment: I do not have any imports, I think the library is built into Processing, you can see it documented here: http://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html

Comment: What package does JSONObject come from?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer myself, but not in the Processing reference, but in the actual reference for the JSONObject class in Java (http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html). I tried some of the methods there and found that hasKey() (which is actually something I came up with myself, combining the method "has()" with the term "key", pure coincidence) as a boolean value works very well:

```
  String preview = "";
  if (CHO.hasKey("edmPreview")) {
    JSONArray previewObj = CHO.getJSONArray("edmPreview");
    String[] previewArray = previewObj.getStringArray();
    preview = previewArray[0];
  }
```

So now I learned that Processing is essentially just Java and sometimes not every method is written in the Reference. :-)